# how to read facebook page feed via app access token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

How could I get the facebook  page feed, when the user isnot loged in.
I could get app access token,after that how I need to fetch data via graph api.
Please provide a sample and could I test that in facebook explore tool.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do is make a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/PAGE_ID?access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

So, for example, to get CocaCola's page feed, the request would look something like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/40796308305/feed
```

The endpoint you're dealing with here is `/{page_id}/feed`. The relevant documentation can be found here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/feed.

For your convenience, here is a link directly to the API explorer with the relevant query:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=40796308305%2Ffeed&version=v2.0

Comment: @I.Sargsyan - you are most welcome! Happy to help! I see from your profile that you don't haven't marked any of the answers you got as accepted. Feel free to take a look at [this meta post] that explains the process of accepting answers. Accepting answers and voting is the best way to thank [so] users :)

Comment: @I.Sargsyan - I'm not sure what SDK you're using, but you can try passing null or empty values for the session - all you really need is the app access token. Although, again, I'm not sure what the requirements of your SDK are...

Comment: @lix- how can i get APP_ACCESS_TOKEN