# Read my own facebook page feed with an app access token in 2022

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm trying to read the page feed of a page I own to display it on my own website with my own styling. This was possible and straight forward in the past, I found for example this question: [how to read facebook page feed via app access token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23739039/how-to-read-facebook-page-feed-via-app-access-token)

But now it seems that app access tokens don't allow you to do that anymore. It seems I really need a user or page access token to do this. However in my scenario there is no login moment. I'm now scrolling through the docs for days and I find myself going in loops. So my question is there a way to do this still in 2022?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could get, the reasoning behind this is: you register an App, and for the app to access your page feed you have to prove you (app user) are an administrator for that page; enter Facebook Login.

Comment: That could be an one time action right, like register an app to a page and give it access. But you still need the user token..